# WP_Query while shows blank page

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress

I want to get all Orders from WooCommerce over WP_Query()

but the while is not ending and i got a blank page 
ourrent query:

```
        $type = 'shop_order';
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => $type,
            'post_status'    => 'any',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );


        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        var_dump($the_query); //This Showes something


        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

            //here comes the blank page
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

            }

        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
```

The var_dump($the_query) is here http://laravel.io/bin/KmwlK

Comment: Are you actually outputing something in the while ? (I know it's obvious but better ask)

Answer (score 0):

In `while ( $the_query->have_posts() )`, you didn't put the function `the_post()`. Maybe use it will solve your problem.

```
//here comes the blank page
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    the_post(); // add it
}
```

Comment: hi, thx but i found a other solution i made this complty wrong

http://laravel.io/bin/nYD49

Comment: instead of `the_post();` , it should be `$the_query->the_post();`.